# How to stop gradient of LSTMStateTuple in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a basic lstm code for language modeling.
But I don't want to do `BPTT`. I want to do something like `tf.stop_gradient(state)`

```
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for time_step in range(N):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
```

However, `state` is `LSTMStateTuple`, so I tried:

```
for lli in range(len(state)):
    print(state[lli].c, state[lli].h)
    state[lli].c = tf.stop_gradient(state[lli].c)
    state[lli].h = tf.stop_gradient(state[lli].h)
```

But I got a `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error:

```
File "/home/liyu-iri/IRRNNL/word-rnn/ptb/models/decoupling.py", line 182, in __init__
state[lli].c = tf.stop_gradient(state[lli].c)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I also tried to use `tf.assign`, but `state[lli].c` is not a variable.

So, I wonder how could I stop gradient of `LSTMStateTuple`?
Or, how could I stop BPTT? I only want to do BP in single frames.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a pure python question: LSTMStateTuple is just a collections.namedtuple and python doesn't allow you to assign elements there (as in other tuples). The solution is to create a fully new one, e.g. like in `stopped_state = LSTMStateTuple(tf.stop_gradient(old_tuple.c), tf.stop_gradient(old_tuple.h))` and then use this (or a list of those) as the state. If you insist on replacing the existing tuple, I think namedtuple has an _replace method, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields), as in `old_tuple._replace(c=tf.stop_gradient(...))`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot!